# using prepared mysqli statements to bind parameters into the SELECT section of a query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am building a web app that imports data from data feeds in php/mysql. I import the data into a buffer/temp holding table. As each data format is different I choose the column to select based on the particular source.

I am having trouble getting this query to work in this context :

```
$stmt = $this->dbObj->prepare("SELECT mk.PK_phone_maker, b.?, b.phoneDescription
            b.thumbPic,
        FROM buffer_table b left join mobile_phone pm on b.? = pm.phoneModel
            LEFT JOIN phone_maker mk on mk.CompanyName = b.?
        WHERE pm.phoneModel is null
        group by b.?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$phoneModelField, $phoneModelField, $phnMakerField,$phoneModelField);
$stmt->execute();
```

I recieve the error msg:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

This refers to the line:

```
 $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$phoneModelField, $phoneModelField,
```

And I assume this is because the "prepare" on my sql hasnt worked as $stmt is not an object

As such it appears to me that you can not bind parameters to select columns and join fields, you can only bind to the where clause. Am I right in this assertion or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements only allow you to bind *values*, other constructs (such as *fields*, *tables* or *functions*, let alone whole bits of SQL) are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

@Victor Nicollet is correct -- you can use a query parameter only in a context where you could have used a *literal value*.

If you need to make other parts of your query variable (e.g. column name, table name, SQL keywords, or whole SQL expressions), you need to build a dynamic SQL query as a string, and interpolate PHP variables or expressions into the string.  Be sure to do this carefully to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

The other WTF in your code is that you didn't check that the `prepare()` function returned an object of type `mysqli_stmt`.  In this case, because you used query parameters in an invalid way, `prepare()` returned *false* to indicate a syntax error.  Of course *false* is not an object; it doesn't have a `bind_param()` method.  That's why you got the error you did.